# What happens to a thread in a vector when function execution ends?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to know more about std::thread, and specifically what will happen if I have a vector of threads, and one of the threads finishes executing.

Picture this example:

A vector of threads is created, which all execute the following function:

```
function_test(char* flag)
{
    while(*flag == 1) { // Do Something
    }
}
```

'char* flag' points to a flag signalling the function to stop execution.

Say, for example, the vector contains 10 threads, which are all executing. Then the flag is set to zero for thread number 3. (The 4th thread in the vector, as vector starts from zero.)

Good practice is to then join the thread.

```
vector_of_threads[3].join();
```

How many std::threads will the vector now contain? Can I re-start the finished thread with the same function again, or even a different function?

The reason for my question is that I have a vector of threads, and sometimes they will be required to stop executing, and then execution "falls off the end" of the function.

One solution to restart that thread would (I assume, perhaps incorrectly?) be to erase that element from the vector and then insert a new thread, which will then begin executing. Is this correct though, since when a thread stops, will it still be inside the vector? I assume it would be?

**Edit**

'function_test' is not allowed to modify any other functions flags. The flags are modified by their own function and the calling function. (For the purposes of this, imagine flag enables communication between main and the thread.)

Does this fix the data-race problem, or is it still an issue?

Answer (score 4):

It's not specifically what you're asking about, but `flag` should be `atomic<char>*` or you have a [data race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#C.2B.2B), i.e. undefined behaviour. Also, if it only holds true or false I'd use `atomic<bool>*` and just test `if (*flag)`.

As for your actual question:

> How many std::threads will the vector now contain?

It will contains exactly the same number as it did previously, but one of them is no longer "joinable" because it doesn't represent a running thread.  When the thread stops running it doesn't magically alter the vector to remove an element, it doesn't even know the vector exists!  The only change visible in the main thread is that calling `vector_of_threads[3].join()` will not block and will return immediately, because the thread has already finished so you don't have to wait to join it.

You could erase the joined `std::thread` from the vector and insert a new one, but another alternative is to assign another `std::thread` to it that represents a new thread of execution:

```
vector_of_threads[3] = std::thread(f, &flags[3]);
```

Now `vector_of_threads[3]` represents a running thread and is "joinable" again.

Comment: Okay that is great, could you explain to me a bit more about the data-race, and how/why this occurs?

Comment: @EdwardBird, one thread executes `if (*flag == 1)` and at some point the other thread sets `flags[3] = 1`, without synchronisation between those threads you have a read and a write to the same memory location which conflict: that's a data race.

Comment: Each thread has it's own independent char* variable/flag.  No other thread will modify another threads flag. I should have mentioned this - I will edit the question.

Comment: Something must modify it, otherwise how does it ever change from its initial value to `1`?

Comment: Err, the main thread? Is this a bad answer? I made an edit, perhaps that shows more clearly what I am trying to do?

Comment: So one thread reads it, and one thread writes it. **That's a data race**.

Comment: Arrgh nooo! I don't actually understand what the problem is going to be, brb - wikipedia.

Comment: I will use atomic variables - because that seems like good practice, however it is not possible for a data-race to occur in this case. Reason being: To signal the thread to exit, the flag is changed to zero. It is then NEVER modified again. It cannot be set back to 1. It may be set to zero more than once, but that is okay. The consequence of this is eventually the correct value will arrive at the function, and the exit condition will be met. But that sounds like something dangerous, so to prevent errors I guess it's time to learn about atomic variables.

Comment: **THAT'S STILL A DATA RACE!**  The act of setting it to 0 (i.e. a write to the memory location), even just once, conflicts with the act of reading it in the other thread.

Comment: I don't understand, since both operations cannot be done at the same time - read and write - then the function must either think the value stored at the location pointed at by 'char*' is high or low. It doesn't actually matter if the value is supposed to be low and the function thinks it's high...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32901/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-edward-bird)